# How to redraw a custom QQuickItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have created a custom QML Element by extending `QQuickItem` and overriding the `updatePaintNode()` function. I am drawing two lines on my application which will expand or shrink in size based on the block size that gets added on the left side of the application. This block can be added in small and big modes and can be removed by selecting the buttons on the top bar.

This is my code:

**line.cpp**

```
#include <QSGGeometry>
#include <QSGGeometryNode>
#include <qsgnode.h>
#include <qsgflatcolormaterial.h>
#include "line.h"

Lines::Lines(QQuickItem *parent) : QQuickItem(parent) {
    setFlag(QQuickItem::ItemHasContents, true);
}

Lines::~Lines() {}

QSGNode *Lines::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData *) {
    QSGGeometryNode *node = NULL;
    QSGGeometry *geometry = NULL;
    QSGGeometry::Point2D *vertices;
    QSGFlatColorMaterial *material;
    int points = 0;
    int lineHeight = 0;
    int ys = 0;
    int xs;
    int xe;

    points = width();

    if (!oldNode)
    {
        node = new QSGGeometryNode;
        geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(), points);
        geometry->setLineWidth(1);
        geometry->setDrawingMode(GL_LINES);
        node->setGeometry(geometry);
        node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsGeometry);
        material = new QSGFlatColorMaterial;
        material->setColor("white");
        node->setMaterial(material);
        node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsMaterial);
    }
    else
    {
        node = static_cast<QSGGeometryNode *>(oldNode);
        geometry = node->geometry();
        geometry->allocate(points);
    }

    vertices = geometry->vertexDataAsPoint2D();
    lineHeight = (height() / 4);

    xs = 0;
    xe = width() - xs;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        ys = ( i * lineHeight);
        vertices[(2*i)].set(xs, ys);
        vertices[(2*i)+1].set(xs + xe, ys);
    }

    node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyForceUpdate);
    return node;
}
```

**line.h**

```
#include <QQuickItem>

class Lines : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Lines(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
    ~Lines();

    QSGNode *updatePaintNode(QSGNode *, UpdatePaintNodeData *);
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "line.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterType<Lines>("lines", 1, 0, "Lines");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import lines 1.0

Window {
    id: canvas

    height: 500
    width: 500
    color: "black"
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: topBar

        height: 40
        Row {
            spacing: 10
            Button {
                text: "Small"
                onClicked: {
                    rect.visible = true
                    rect.width = 50
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: "Big"
                onClicked: {
                    rect.visible = true
                    rect.width = 100
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: "None"
                onClicked: {
                    rect.visible = false
                    rect.width = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect

        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            top: topBar.bottom
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        color: "grey"
        visible: false
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2

        anchors {
            left: rect.right
            right: parent.right
            top: topBar.bottom
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        color: "black"

        Lines {
            id: lines

            x: 0
            y: 100

            width: parent.width
            height: 225
        }
    }
}
```

I am seeing that when I select the left Grey block (using the buttons) the Lines were not redrawn properly and I see some glitches. The attached picture below shows my output with glitches.

[image: Output of the Code]

I have tried calling `node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyForceUpdate)` but it is of no use.

How can I fix this issue. Please help. Thanks in advance.